# meteor - lukemadera:autoform-googleplace

Tags: meteor

I've installed `lukemadera:autoform-googleplace` package and followed the usage instructions. When I run the application the address field doesn't auto populate as I type. I get an error in console `(Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined)` can someone please tell me what I'm missing.

Path: `Layout.html`

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>  
</head>
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
Schema.Address = new SimpleSchema({
    fullAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true
    },
    lng: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true
    },
    geometry: {
        type: Object,
        blackbox: true
    },
    placeId: {
        type: String
    },
    street: {
        type: String,
        max: 100
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        max: 50
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]$/
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[0-9]{5}$/
    },
    country: {
        type: String
    }
});

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    address: {
        type: Schema.Address,
        optional: true
    }
});
```

Path: `personalDetails.js`

```
<template name="personalDetails">
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" id="candidateProfile" doc=currentUser type="update"}}

    {{> afQuickField name="profile.address" type="googleplace" opts=optsGoogleplace}}

{{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Path: `personalDetails.js`

```
Template.personalDetails.helpers({
  optsGoogleplace: function() {
    return {
      // type: 'googleUI',
      // stopTimeoutOnKeyup: false,
      // googleOptions: {
      //   componentRestrictions: { country:'us' }
      // }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: did you try to put the `EJSON is not defined` into google to see what is going on ?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find anything. In the instructions it doesn't mention anything about setting up a json file. Could this be the problem?

Comment: noo. it is because you are missing a package. the first google result from my place immediately show the solution

Comment: OMG, I did read that post and I checked meteor version and saw this `ejson@1.0.7`. I assumed that meant it was a standard part of meteor now. Anyway, I've added the package and the console log error disappears and the autoform works. Do you know why that would happen? Thanks again @ThaiTran

Comment: i am not sure if `ejson` is default or not. but if i see that message, that means a package could be missing

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, just in case someone else gets this error, you need to install [ejson](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ejson).